# Trouble with multiple model observers in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm stuck on a weird issue.  It feels like in Laravel, you're not allowed to have multiple model observers listening to the same event.  In my case:

*Parent Model*

```
class MyParent extends Eloquent {
   private static function boot()
   {
      parent::boot();
      $called_class = get_called_class();
      $called_class::creating(function($model) {
         doSomethingInParent();
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

*Child Model*

```
class MyChild extends myParent {
   private static function boot()
   {
      parent::boot();
      MyChild::creating(function($model) {
         doSomethingInChild();
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

In the above example, if I do:

$instance = MyChild::create();

... the line doSomethingInChild() will not fire.  doSomethingInParent(), does.

If I move parent::boot() within the child *after* MyChild::creating(), however, it does work.  (I didn't confirm whether doSomethingInParent() fires, but I'm presuming it doesn't)

Can Laravel have multiple events registered to Model::creating()?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This one is tricky.  Short version: Remove your return values from you handlers and both events will fire.  Long version follows.

First, I'm going to assume you meant to type `MyParent` (not `myParent`), that you meant your `boot` methods to be `protected`, and not `private`, and that you included a final `)` in your `create` method calls.  Otherwise your code doesn't run. :)

However, the problem you describe is real.  The reason for it is certain Eloquent events are considered "halting" events.  That is, for some events, if **any** non-null value is returned from the event handlers (be it a closure or PHP callback), the event will stop propagating.  You can see this in the dispatcher

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php
public function fire($event, $payload = array(), $halt = false)
{
}
```

See that third parameter `$halt`?  Later on, while the dispatcher is calling event listeners

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php
    foreach ($this->getListeners($event) as $listener)
    {
        $response = call_user_func_array($listener, $payload);

        // If a response is returned from the listener and event halting is enabled
        // we will just return this response, and not call the rest of the event
        // listeners. Otherwise we will add the response on the response list.
        if ( ! is_null($response) && $halt)
        {
            array_pop($this->firing);

            return $response;
        }

    //...
```

If halt is `true` and the callback returned **anything** that's not null (`true`, `false`, a sclaer value, an `array`, an `object`), the `fire` method short circuits with a `return $response`, and the events stop propagating.   This is above and beyond that standard "return `false` to stop event propagation".  Some events have halting built in.

So, which Model events halt?  If you look at the definition of `fireModelEvent` in the base eloquent model class (Laravel aliases this as `Eloquent`)

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
protected function fireModelEvent($event, $halt = true)
{
    //...
}
```

You can see a model's events **default** to halting. So, if we look through the model for firing events, we see the events that **do** halt are

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
$this->fireModelEvent('deleting') 
$this->fireModelEvent('saving')
$this->fireModelEvent('updating')
$this->fireModelEvent('creating')
```

and events that don't halt are

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
$this->fireModelEvent('booting', false);
$this->fireModelEvent('booted', false);
$this->fireModelEvent('deleted', false);
$this->fireModelEvent('saved', false);
$this->fireModelEvent('updated', false);
$this->fireModelEvent('created', false);
```

As you can see, `creating` is a halting event, which is why returning any value, even `true`, halted the event and your second listener didn't fire. Halting events are typically used when the Model class wants to do something with the return value from an event.  Specifically for `creating`

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
protected function performInsert(Builder $query)
{
    if ($this->fireModelEvent('creating') === false) return false;
    //...
```

if you return `false`, (not null) from your callback, Laravel will actually skip performing the `INSERT`.  Again, this is different behavior from the standard *stop event propagation by returning false*.  In the case of these four model events, returning `false` will also cancel the action they're listening for.

Remove the return values (or `return null`) and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Brilliant!  I suppose if I think hard enough, it makes sense.  If one listener cancels the creation, the other listeners shouldn't fire.  I was just surprised that returning "true" was also halting as well.  Anywho, great explanation AlanStorm - thanks!

Comment: @Anthony It is a little  weird/non-obvious, but there's no easy win here.   This is why systems like Drupal have an event system for events, and a "hooks" system for events that need to manipulate data.

Comment: This is such a huge surprise and the way it works is so obscure that it should be considered bad practice to use. There used to be a bit about this in the Laravel docs, "Cancelling save operations", but now even that is gone. You'll note that the "haltable" events all end with `-ing`... so if you want to stop something that's *being* processed, just throw an exception. Free benefit: if it does occur, it won't go unnoticed.